# golang multiplication algorithm in html template

Tags: algorithm, templates, go

I am new for golang. I met a problem when I use multiplication in html/template.
Some code like below.

template code:

```
 {{range $i,$e:=.Items}}
      <tr>
           <td>{{add $i (mul .ID .Number)}}</td>
           <td>{{.Name}}</td>
      </tr>
  {{end}}
```

.go code

```
type Item struct{
        ID int
        Name string
    }
func init() {
    itemtpl,_:=template.New("item.gtpl").
        Funcs(template.FuncMap{"mul": Mul, "add": Add}).
        ParseFiles("./templates/item.gtpl")
}

func itemHandle(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {

    items:=[]Item{Item{1,"name1"},Item{2,"name2"}}
    data := struct {
            Items []Item
            Number int
            Number2 int
        }{
            Items:    items,
            Number:   5,
            Number2:  2,
        }
        itemtpl.Execute(w, data)
}
func Mul(param1 int, param2 int) int {
    return param1 * param2
}
func Add(param1 int, param2 int) int {
    return param1 + param2
}
```

It will output nothing when I use the code above. But It will output 10 when I use the code outside of array below.

```
<html>
<body>
    {{mul .Number .Number2}}
</html>
</body>
```

I google a lot. I cannot find the usable like mine. I want to use multiplication in array inside of html/template. Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`template.Execute()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Execute) returns an [`error`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#error), you should always check that. Would you have done so:

> template: item.gtpl:3:33: executing "item.gtpl" at <.Number>: Number is not a field of struct type main.Item

The "problem" is that `{{range}}` changes the pipeline (the *dot*, `.`) to the current item, so inside the `{{range}}`:

```
{{add $i (mul .ID .Number)}}
```

`.Number` will refer to a field or method of your `Item` type since you are looping over a `[]Item`. But your `Item` type has no such method or field.

Use `$.Number` which will refer to the "top-level" `Number` and not a field of the current `Item` value:

```
{{add $i (mul .ID $.Number)}}
```

Try your modified, working code on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/34HgBb_OhZ).

`$` is documented at [`text/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/):

> When execution begins, $ is set to the data argument passed to Execute, that is, to the starting value of dot.

Comment: I wrote it manually. Sorry for no testing. Do you mean I must define a new field for Item type? But I have many structs like Item. Has other way to do it instead of defining the new field for all structs.

Comment: @Johnson Please edited answer. You don't need to add a new field to `Item`. You just need to change `.Number` to `$.Number` and it will work.